# How to abstract out same method with different return types in multiple classes

Tags: java, class, refactoring

I apologize if I didn't ask the question correctly in advance.

I have about 15 related classes using the same code but different return types.  How would I abstract that out to avoid code duplication in all these classes?

```
    public ChargeResponse findByTransactionId(final String txId) {
        ChargeResponse chargeResponse = null;
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(VIEW_SERVICE_TRANSACTION_CHARGE_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txId);
            final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            chargeResponse = parseQueryResults(resultSet);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chargeResponse;
    }
```

```
    public EventsResponse findByTransactionId(final String txId) {
        EventsResponse eventsResponse = null;
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(VIEW_SERVICE_TRANSACTION_EVENTS_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txId);
            final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            eventsResponse = parseQueryResults(resultSet);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return eventsResponse;
    }
```

and so on..

Comment: I think this question is better to post in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> T findByTransactionId(final String txId) {
    T chargeResponse;
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(VIEW_SERVICE_TRANSACTION_CHARGE_QUERY);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, txId);
        final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        chargeResponse = parseQueryResults(resultSet);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return chargeResponse;
}
```

Do the same with parseQueryResults. Then move those methods to parent class.

Answer (score 0):

If the `XXXResponse` types share a common super-type (class or interface), you can even solve it without generics, similar to @dubilyer's solution. (And for the love of future generations of programmers, do something about that silly `catch`-block ;-)